# How to understand the css px and device resolution?

Tags: css, frontend

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have two screens with different resolutions. The high-resolution one has a resolution of 2560*1600, and the devicePixelRatio is 2, But why the CSS width is 1440px? Shouldn't it be 1280px?

So finally, I found that the screen display resolution is zoomable. So 1440 is the display resolution related.  But why the devicePixelRatio is fixed to 2?

Comment: Is your width 2560 or 1600?

Comment: The width is 2560 and height is 1600.

Comment: Are you using the IE by any chance? It might be depending on the zoom factor of your monitor (see [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width)).

Comment: What are you getting as height? And could we see the code you are using?

Comment: I found this [article](https://elad.medium.com/understanding-the-difference-between-css-resolution-and-device-resolution-28acae23da0b) really helpful.Try out whether this gives you the answer.

Comment: @DininduGunathilaka Thanks a lot! But that article does not clear my confusion. I think now my confusion turn to the adjustable display resolution. As my last pic shows, the css width is the same as the display resolution，what's relationship between the display resolution and screen resolution?